# jQuery make sure all form fields are filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a simple form I'm making client side validation for.
To validate, none of the fields should be left blank.
This is how I go at it:

```
function validateForm() {
  $('.form-field').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).val() === '' ) {
      return false
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
  });
}
```

For some reason, my function always returns false, even though all fields are filled.

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything. Each is calling the inner function for every .form-field element. validateForm never returns a value.

Comment: I had a feeling this was the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You cannot return false from within the anonymous function. In addition, if it did work, you would return false if your first field was empty, true if not, and completely ignore the rest of your fields. There may be a more elegant solution but you can do something like this:

```
function validateForm() {
  var isValid = true;
  $('.form-field').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).val() === '' )
        isValid = false;
  });
  return isValid;
}
```

Another recommendation: this requires you to decorate all of your form fields with that formfield class. You may be interested in filtering using a different selector, e.g. `$('form.validated-form input[type="text"]')`

**EDIT** Ah, I got beat to the punch, but my explanation is still valid and hopefully helpful.

Comment: Yup very helpful, thanks! I knew I was not doing this the right way regarding the return. Good suggestion for the $('form input[type="text"]') thanks for that too, it's cleaner.

Comment: Oh, shoot, you'd want to put a class name on your form, otherwise you will validate every form on the screen!

Comment: Or $('form.validated-form :input') to capture text fields.

Comment: $(':required') is the more elegant approach, actually respects ANY elements that are defined semantically as required

Answer (score 6):

You were returning from the inner function not from the `validate` method

Try

```
function validateForm() {
    var valid = true;
    $('.form-field').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            valid = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return valid
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function validateForm() {
    var invalid= 0;
    $('.form-field').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            invalid++;
        }
    });

   if(invalid>0)
       return false;
   else
       return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a similar approach:

```
function validateForm() {
  var valid = true;
  $('.form-field').each(function() {
    valid &= !!$(this).val();
  });
  return valid;
}
```

`!!` just converts input value to bool