# enabling button when all the fields are filled up

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout.js for data binding.Actually there is a form which some fields accepting name,number,email etc.Suppose if any one of the field is not filled and the save button is pressed then that button goes to disabled state.Till now its working fine.

Now if I fill the empty fields then I want to enable that button again and I dont know how to do.Can any body please help me how to do?

The following is the js code

```
self.newPatient = ko.asyncCommand({

    execute: function (complete) {
        var isValid = $('#addPatientForm').parsley('validate');
        if (isValid) {
            var patientJson = ko.toJSON(self.patient());
            formdata.append("json", patientJson);
            //self.enableButton(false); 
            var imagepath = $.ajax({
                url: projectUrl + "newPatient",
                type: "POST",
                data: formdata,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (res) {
                    formdata = new FormData();
                    imagepath = res;
                    var length = self.patients().length;
                    var patient = self.patient();
                    //  self.enableButton(true); 
                }
            });
            $('.alert-patient-success').show();
            self.patients.removeAll();
            self.getPatients();
            /* $.when(self.patients.push(self.patient()),self.patient(new Patient()),self.dirtyFlag1().reset(),$('#patientTabs a:last').tab('show')) 
.always(complete);*/
        }
    },
    canExecute: function (isExecuting) {
        return !isExecuting && isDirty() && isValid();
    }
});
```

this is html code

```
<script id="patientMetadataTemplate" type="text/html"> 
<form id="addPatientForm" data-validate="parsley"> 
<div class="control-group"> 
<label class="control-label" for="inputIcon">Name :</label> 
<div class="controls"> 
<div class="input-prepend" > 
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i></span> 
<input class="span8" type="text" data-bind="value: name" data-required="true" data-trigger="change" name="name"> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="control-group"> 
<label class="control-label" for="inputIcon">Address :</label> 
<div class="controls"> 
<div class="input-prepend"> 
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i></span> 
<input class="span8" name="address" type="text" data-bind="value: address" data-required="true" data-trigger="change"> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div>
```

I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqG8g/1/) also for the above js and html.

Comment: 1) add a handler that triggers when any input is changed 2) in that handler, check all fields have a value 3) enable submit button
see this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469999/jquery-how-to-check-if-form-elements-are-not-empty

Answer (score 4):

something like this:

```
var formCompleted = false;
$('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');

$(":text, :file, :checkbox, select, textarea").change(function() {
  formCompleted = validateForm();   
  if(formCompleted){
    $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});

function validateForm() {
  var isValid = true;
  $('.form-field').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).val() === '' )
      isValid = false;
    });
  return isValid;
}
```

First you disable the button, on each form element change you check if it is filled out and then you remove the disabled attr. I haven't tested this, but it should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: you have used `form-field` so can you tell me to which does this refer to?

Comment: this is a class you should add to each form-field. it's an alternative way to get each form element.
Just realised I haven't linked to that page, so I "stole" that function from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907198/jquery-make-sure-all-form-fields-are-filled

Comment: the problem is in my project knockout dirtyflag is used and for that this is happening.If I use jquery code for that the button is getting disabled but the when i press the button then control is not going to `self.newPatient = ko.asyncCommand({....}`

Comment: Can't you call the the knockout functionality from within the jquery code? I haven't used knockout, so I'll leave the 'helpful' comments to others :-)