# HTML form with feedback if user didn't answer all questions

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit

I am trying to find a javascript solution for reminding the user that not all of the fields, radiobuttons, etc. in a HTML form have been answered. I found solutions for denying the user to submit the form with "required fields", but this is not what I want to do. The user should be simply reminded (e.g. "Please note that you didn't answer all of the questions on this page") and then asked if she/he wants to continue (e.g. "Do you want to continue anyway? [Yes/No]".

Maybe someone has an example how to achieve that!

Thanks in advance,
Benjamin

--edit:
Sorry people I am not very experienced with html stuff, so it's difficult for me to get what you are proposing. Thank you anyway for your replies so far! I'll try to make it more clear -- my html file contains several blocks like this:

```
<tr>
<td>Question X: How important ... </td>
<td></td>
<td width="40" align="center"><input type=radio name="<ml.varname>_01" value="1" >1</td>
<td width="40" align="center"><input type=radio name="<ml.varname>_01" value="2" >2</td>
<td width="40" align="center"><input type=radio name="<ml.varname>_01" value="3" >3</td>
</tr>
```

It is basically a questionaire with a bunch of Likert scales. If one or more (or all) of this scales are not answered, the participant should be informed about that, but still allowing the participant to continue after being informed.

Other lines which may be important are:

```
<form method="post">
```

and in the end:

```
<tr><td><input type=submit value="Continue"></td></tr>
</table></form>
```

How do I define a "common class for form elements like form-field in my script" as @Hoja.M.A proposes? And how to make sure the javascript file is called by my html file?

Thank you in advance! I hope it is a bit clearer now ... **Please note** that I am a total noob when it comes to javascript and html forms, so please don't expect too much backgroud knowledge...

Comment: I added more information on what my html form looks like. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Do Simple javascript validations for all fields. Then use `confirm()` method to prompt user `yes` or `no`.
example:

```
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to continue?')) {
    // Save it!
} else {
    // Do nothing!
}
```

Check this [Pop-up](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp) links for more info.

Answer (score 1):

as you mentioned that you are able to check that if a user does not fills all required fields how to restrict the user from submission you can use confirm on that place.

```
confirm("Do you want to continue anyway? ");
```

it will return ok and cancel options alert box

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a function, `myFormIsValid`, which returns `true` if all fields are filled; and a `submitMyForm` method which submits the form, you can use [`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm) to prompt the user.

For example, in your `onSubmit` code:

```
if(myFormIsValid() || confirm("Do you want to continue anyway?")) {
    submitMyForm();
}
```

This way, if the form is valid, it will be submitted. If the form is not valid, it will prompt the user. If they click 'Yes', the form will be submitted. Otherwise, the form will not be submitted.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. I am still unsure how to write this function myFormIsValid you mentioned. I know: several other people described how to do it, but I still wonder how the "fields" are identified who should be checked. I added more info on my html form in my original post however. Maybe you can help me to sort out how to check all the radio button "blocks" I am describing there.

Answer (score 1):

```
1. First of all you have to give a common class for form elements like form-field in my script.
2. Then on submit call this function validateForm if it returns false you could simply show a confirm box.





     $('YOUR FORM').on('submit',function(){
        var isChecked = validateForm();
          if(!isChecked){
           confirm('Please note that you didn't answer all of the questions on this page');
           }
        });
        function validateForm() {
              var isValid = true;
              $('.form-field').each(function() {
                if ( $(this).val() === '' )
                    isValid = false;
              });
              return isValid;
            }
```

Comment: This looks great. Unfortunately I don't know how to implement your **First** step. I added more information in my additional post, however. Can you please give me another hint how to implement your suggestion?

Comment: I mean give a class attribute to your elements for 
eg: 
<input type=radio class=""form-field name="<ml.varname>_01">
then add an ID to form "<form id="myForm">"
then you could call the function as $('#myForm').on('submit',function(){
var isChecked = validateForm();
          if(!isChecked){
           confirm('Please note that you didn't answer all of the questions on this page');
           }
});

Same as above.

Comment: Is it <input type=radio class=""form-field name="<ml.varname>_01"> like you wrote, or is it <input type=radio class="form-field" name="<ml.varname>_01"> ?

Comment: An additional question: Where does the last part $('#myForm').on('submit',function(){ var isChecked = validateForm(); if(!isChecked){ confirm('Please note that you didn't answer all of the questions on this page'); } }); go in the html file? Inside the <script> environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `confirm('are you sure?');`. An alert-like thing will pop on the window.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a JavaScript function to check all of fields have a value. If they don't you could .show() an element with the warning message.

Example function [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907198/jquery-make-sure-all-form-fields-are-filled):

```
function validateForm() {
  var isValid = true;
  $('.form-field').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).val() === '' )
        isValid = false;
  });
  return isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 onsubmit="return checkAllFields()" add this even to your form field.
```

Use javascript to validate all the fields, I am writing the work flow for you to get the idea.

```
<script>
function checkAllFields(){

if(FIELD.VALUE==""){
 alert("your message");
return false
}
else 
return true;
}
```

return submit as false when all the fields are not selected..