# javascript Function doesn't return any value

Tags: javascript

I want to enable the submit button if all the fields are filled in the correct pattern, but it is not working. I tried to store return value in variables for each function, but no changes made, all validations run pretty good but the disabled submit button doesn't become enabled.

I can't get returned value in a variable. Any help is apreciated. Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    function Val_Fname()
    {
        $("#f_name").keyup(function(){
            var fn = $(this).val();
            if(fn.length<=0)
            {
                $(this).attr("Placeholder","Required Field");
                $(this).attr("style","color:red;");
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                var reg = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
                if(reg.test(fn))
                {
                    $(this).attr("style","color:Black;");
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).attr("style","color:red;");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    function Val_Mname()
    {
        $("#m_name").keyup(function(){
            var mn = $(this).val();
            if(mn.length<=0)
            {
                $(this).attr("Placeholder","Required Field");
                $(this).attr("style","color:red;");
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                var reg = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
                if(reg.test(mn))
                {
                    $(this).attr("style","color:Black;");
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).attr("style","color:red;");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    function Val_Lname()
    {
        $("#l_name").keyup(function(){
            var ln = $(this).val();
            if(ln.length<=0)
            {
                $(this).attr("Placeholder","Required Field");
                $(this).attr("style","color:red;");
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                var reg = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
                if(reg.test(ln))
                {
                    $(this).attr("style","color:Black;");
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).attr("style","color:red;");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    function Val_em()
    {
        $("#email").keyup(function(){
            var em = $(this).val();
            if(em.length<=0)
            {
                $(this).attr("placeholder","Email can not be blank");
                $(this).attr("style","color:red;");
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                var reg = /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/;
                if(reg.test(em))
                {
                    $(this).attr("style","color:Black;");
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).attr("style","color:red;");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    function Val_en()
    {
        $("#enroll").keyup(function(){
            var enroll = $(this).val();
            if(enroll.length<=0)
            {
                $(this).attr("placeholder","Enrollment can not be blank");
                $(this).attr("style","color:red;");
                return 0;
            }
            else if(enroll.length>12 || enroll.length<12) {
                $(this).attr("style","color:red;");
                return 0;
            }
            else if(enroll.length= =12)
                {
            var reg=/^[0-9][0-9]{11}$/;
            if(reg.test(enroll))
            {
                $(this).attr("style","color:Black;");
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).attr("style","color:red;");
                return 0;
            }
        });
    }
    function Val_mb()
    {
        $("#mobile").keyup(function(){
            var mob=$(this).val();
            if(mob.length<=0)
            {
                $(this).attr("placeholder","Mobile Number can not be blank");
                $(this).attr("style","color:red;");
                return 0;
            }
            else if(mob.length>10 || mob.length<10)
            {
                $(this).attr("style","color:red;");
                return 0;
            }
            else if(mob.length==10)
            {
                var reg = /^[0-9][0-9]{9}$/;
                if(reg.test(mob))
                {
                    $(this).attr("style","color:Black;");
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).attr("style","color:red;");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function submitbutton()
    {
        var z = Val_Fname();
        var y = Val_Mname();
        var x = Val_Lname();
        var w = Val_em();
        var v = Val_en();
        var u = Val_mb();

        if(z==1 && y==1 && x==1 && w==1 && v==1 && u==1)
        {
            $("#subs_btn").attr("disabled",false);
            $("#subs_btn").attr("style","background:rgba(0, 186, 107, 0.71);");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#subs_btn").attr("disabled",true);
            $("#subs_btn").attr("style","background:grey;");
        }
    }
    submitbutton();

    $("#subs_btn").click(function(){
        $("#reg_form").submit();
    });
});
```

```css
form
{
 display:block;
 width:35%;
 margin:10em auto;
 text-align:center;
 box-shadow:0px 4px 8px #818080;
 background:#eee;
 border-top-right-radius:7px;
 border-top-left-radius:7px;
 font-family:calibri;
 padding:1em;
 overflow:hidden;
}
form input[type="button"]
{
 width: 66.2%;
 padding: .7em;
 background: rgba(0, 186, 107, 0.71);
 border: none;
 color: #fefefe;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-top: 1em;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 text-shadow:0px 0px 10px black;
}
form input[type="reset"]
{
 width:20%;
 padding: .7em;
 background: rgba(89, 93, 91, 0.7);
 border: none;
 color: #fefefe;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-top: 1em;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 text-shadow:0px 0px 10px black;
}
form input[type="text"]
{
 margin:.3em;
 width:40%;
 padding:.3em;
}
form h4
{
 display:block;
 background:#757575;
 margin:-.8em;
 margin-bottom:0.6em;
 padding:.7em;
 font-size:1.5em;
 color:#fffcfc;
 text-shadow:0px 0px 10px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JS Form Validation</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form method="get" id="reg_form">
  <h4>Student Registration Form</h4>
  <input type="text" name="f_name" id="f_name" placeholder="First Name">
  <input type="text" name="m_name" id="m_name" placeholder="Middle Name">
  <input type="text" name="l_name" id="l_name" placeholder="Last Name">
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
  <input type="text" name="enroll" id="enroll" placeholder="Enrollment No">
  <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile">
  <input type="button" id="subs_btn" value="Subscribe">
  <input type="Reset" name="Reset" id="Reset" value="Reset">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi,check this answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907198/jquery-make-sure-all-form-fields-are-filled and in addition to that accepted answer i would control every submit values in your form everytime a user enters something to the fields. IF everything is ok. then enable the button.

Comment: Instead of returning a value from inside the keyup event handlers, you need to call a function, passing in the value you would like to return.

Comment: In Your Jquery method `Val_en()` method was having some syntax issue, extra braces you have added by mistake I guess. due to that may be its not working. I have edited your code part of Js. Check Now. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

i have added a comment but it wont fit in that area.

So here is the problem you are having right now.

```
function Val_mb()
    {
        $("#mobile").keyup(function(){
            var mob = $(this).val();
            if(mob.length<=0)
```

This section of your code both requires a call to function as well as a keyup trigger everytime you hit a button. So lets seperate them. Instead of using  `fucntion Val_mb()` like this.

Define this global variables here in your "document ready section" then remove the above part like this.

$("#mobile").keyup(function(){
   if(everything is ok){
      set global variable to true or false
   }
}

here is your function

```
function Val_mb(){
   return that global variable;
}
```

we can re arrange all the key up function and seperate. then it should work.

```
document ready {
var elementOneBooleanIdentifier = false;
var elementTwoBooleanIdentifier = false;
var elementThreeBooleanIdentifier = false;
var elementFourBooleanIdentifier = false;

$("elementOneidentifier").keyup(function(){
    if (element 1 have the right values)
        set its boolean identifier to true or false;
});
$("elementTwoidentifier").keyup(function(){
    if (element 2 have the right values)
        set its boolean identifier to true or false;
});
$("elementThreeidentifier").keyup(function(){
    if (element 3 have the right values)
        set its boolean identifier to true or false;
});
$("elementFouridentifier").keyup(function(){
    if (element 4 have the right values)
        set its boolean identifier to true or false;
});



functions goes here..

return that elements boolean identifiers
```

}

hope it helps
thanks